# Own process instance can not be found inside a ServiceTask execution

Tags: java, camunda

I have implemented a Camunda ServiceTask class (JavaDelegate) right after the start of my process. In this task I run a ProcessInstanceQuery for the *own* process instance (don't ask why). Surprisingly the query result is null - and I do not understand how this can happen.

To reproduce the problem I created a very simple demo project at [GitHub](https://github.com/FrVaBe/camunda/tree/master/camunda-hello-world).

This is the process

[image]

and this is my [HelloWorldTask](https://github.com/FrVaBe/camunda/blob/master/camunda-hello-world/src/main/java/hello/world/HelloWorldTask.java) execution code

```
@Override
public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

    String processInstanceId = execution.getProcessInstanceId();

    System.out.println(
            "Entering HelloWorldTask.execute (processInstanceId=" + processInstanceId + ")");

    ProcessInstanceQuery query =
            runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId);
    ProcessInstance pi = query.singleResult();

    if (pi == null) {
        System.out
                .println("WARN - No process instance with id " + processInstanceId + " found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    System.out.println(
            "Exiting HelloWorldTask.execute (processInstanceId=" + processInstanceId + ")");

}
```

There is a unit test `hello.word.HelloWorldTest.helloWorld()` which can be used to start the process. The output unfortunately is

```
Entering HelloWorldTask.execute (processInstanceId=4)
WARN - No process instance with id 4 found!
Exiting HelloWorldTask.execute (processInstanceId=4)
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour. Would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have no wait states the transaction is not comited, which means there is no process instance in the database, until the end of the process.

To access the process instance via your delegate execution simply use
the `execution.getProcessInstance()` method.
This method returns itself, if the delegate execution is currently the process instance. In your case it will be the same execution.

For more information about wait states and transaction boundaries in the Camunda Engine please see the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/).

Comment: First of all thanks. The `execution.getProcessInstance` returns a `DelegateExecution` which is not the same as a `ProcessInstance` that I would get when using the ProcessInstanceQuery. Nevertheless you are right, that all information that I need probably is also available via the DelegateExecution. But nevertheless I would have expected that a created/running process is also queryable via the RuntimeService. What does it mean that the process is only commited on _wait_ states?

Comment: @FrVaBe please see my updated answer and the link to the docs for Wait States. The DelegateExecution has all information's you need and more than the ProcessInstance interface itself. On runtime the returned object is of type ExecutionEntity which is a ProcessInstance and also a DelegateExecution. You can cast if you whish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am wondering now if a process without wait state (e.g. only with ServiceTasks) will never be persisted and therefore not be "visible" via the API? (I suppose I have to read and understand the _Transactions in Processes_ documentation in more datail)

Comment: Hey @FrVaBe the process instance will be persisted in the end of the process or on any wait state (and on transaction boundaries like async before and after)

Comment: Explanation why these queries work the way they do: https://forum.camunda.org/t/camunda-transaction-flushing-querying-from-cache/762/2?u=thorben