# Is there an easy way to find out if the process is waiting in a UserTask inside Delegation Code?

Tags: java, camunda

This question is about the Camunda BPM engine.

I would like to implement an ExecutionListener that I can attach to any process events. This listener should send process state messages to a message queue. The process message should contain a state that would be "PENDING" for the process if the process is waiting in a UserTask somewhere.

Now I wonder if there is an easy way to find out if the process is waiting (somewhere) in a UserTask inside the Delegation Code (by using provided `DelegateExecution` object of the delegation code method). Could not find one so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.ExecutionListener;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.runtime.ActivityInstance;

public class ExampleExecutionListener implements ExecutionListener {

  public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
    RuntimeService runtimeService = execution.getProcessEngineServices().getRuntimeService();
    ActivityInstance activityInstance = runtimeService.getActivityInstance(execution.getProcessInstanceId());

    boolean isInAnyUserTask = isInAnyUserTask(activityInstance);
  }

  protected boolean isInAnyUserTask(ActivityInstance activityInstance) {
    if ("userTask".equals(activityInstance.getActivityType())) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      for (ActivityInstance child : activityInstance.getChildActivityInstances()) {
        boolean isChildInUserTask = isInAnyUserTask(child);
        if (isChildInUserTask) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this does not consider called process instances.

Comment: This only shows if the current execution is an user task. Op wants to know from the current execution if the process is somewhere else in an user task.

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to know if the current element is a user task but if the overall ProcessInstance this task belongs to, is _somewhere_ waiting in a UserTask.

Comment: Probably a working solution, but if I need to go via the ProcessEngineServices would it not be easier to just query for the UserTasks like `taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(execution.getProcessInstanceId()).list().isEmpty()` (suggested by @smsnheck and @webjockey)

Comment: @FrVaBe I have found exactly this solution a few weeks ago. I think this is the best solution (also because I don't know any other ;-) )

Comment: @smsnheck If you update your answer I would tend to accept it - unless there is no explanation why this answer is better. Nevertheless +1 for this answer because I learned how to access the process engine services via the DelegationExecution object ;-)

Comment: @FrVaBe `taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(execution.ge‌​tProcessInstanceId()‌​).list().isEmpty()` does not work when the task is created in the same transaction, because queries do not work on cache state (see your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419267/own-process-instance-can-not-be-found-inside-a-servicetask-execution). `RuntimeService#getActivityInstance` does work on cached state and can deal with these cases. If this does not matter in your use case, both solutions are equally well suited and the task query is more concise, so I'd prefer that.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will combine `execution.getBpmnModelElementInstance() instanceof UserTask` and the task query in this case. Hope this works.

Comment: @thorben - nice one, did not know about the getActivityInstance trick ... this will be useful for a problem I have, where I need access in task#create but cannot get it if I am on the first task in a new process instance ...

Answer (score 1):

There is an interface `TaskListener`. You can implement it by yourself and append your own `TaskListener` to each UserTask in the BPMN code. You can also define on which event type your own `TaskListener`should be executed (create, assignment, complete, delete).

The `notify`-method is called with a `DelegateTask` which contains more specific information about the concrete UserTask. You could extract the information and send these information into your queue (when you call your implementation of the `TaskListener`on the create event).

Otherwise you can use the `TaskService` to create a query to retrieve all open tasks. For a working query you need the process instance id of the current execution, which you can retrieve from the delegate execution. To make things short take this code snippet: `taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(delegateExecution.ge‌​tProcessInstanceId()‌​).list().isEmpty()`.

Comment: At the moment I implemented an `ExecutionListener` which works fine. I just need to know if there is a way to find out - in the `notify` method - if the process is _somewhere_ waiting inside a UserTask

Comment: I don't have a working camunda installation right now here on my workstation. But have you looked at the `org.camunda.bpm.engine.TaskService`? The method I'm looking at is the `taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();` method. Maybe this could help you.

Comment: Thanks - running a task query will probably do the job but I wondered if there is a simpler solution via the `DelegateExecution` object.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I've also searched some months ago a similar solution. I realized then that you can't jump from the current `DelegateExecution` to a higher level ("main process instance") and look where the process is waiting on another user task. Therefor you need some more services. Like the `Task-` or `RuntimeService`

Comment: Finally accepted @thorbens answer because it (together with the comments) gives the most comprehensive answer to my special problem - whereas this answer only affects my particular problem in one paragraph. Nevertheless the solution explained in this paragraph is part of my solution, therefore thanks and +1.

Answer (score 1):

DelegateExecution does not have all the information that you need. You will have to use the task query to see whether it returns at least 1 result on the process instance that is currently running.