# Retrieve the number of assigned and unassigned UserTasks inside Camunda Listeners

Tags: java, camunda

I need to retrieve the number of assigned and unassigned UserTasks of a processInstance inside the Camunda BPM DelegateListeners and TaskListeners notify methods.

It is no problem to get the values from a task query, but that only includes the transaction scope. Is there any chance to retrieve these values also inside the listener notify method - thus also for the cached scope. I already tried to combine the task query with the cached scope (e.g. by incrementing the assignedTaskCount on TaskListener "assignment" events) but it is hard to get transaction and cached scope in sync.

Maybe there is a possible solution via the `ActivityInstance`s of the process (like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489249/367285) for other reasons) - but I could not find out if and how. Would be very helpfull for me to know.

At the moment I use process variables to store sets of assigned tasks and unassigned tasks which I update on process events - but I'd rather avoid it.

PS: I used the *transaction scope* term for the committed Camunda state and the *cached scope* term for the state between two Camunda commits. Not sure if this is the right terminology - but I think I read it somewhere.

Comment: Not sure which class you are referring to, you can always call BPMPlatform.getProcessEngine() to get hold of the process engine and perform queries

Comment: @webjockey Yes I have either `DelegateTask` or `DelegateExecution` instances available. But as I said a query does not deliver the complete answers as the result does not include the "state" after the last Camunda commit (what I call _cached_ state).

Comment: Use asyncBefore at your service task, which calls your delegate, to commit the transaction. The service task will be executed with the help of asynchronous continuation. See the docuementation https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/#asynchronous-continuations

Comment: @Zelldon Might help for service tasks. At the moment I struggle more with UserTasks in parallel execution. I think I observed that the wait state is first reached, when all UserTasks were created. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Camunda does batch updates between transaction boundaries; it may even decide to update commits towards end of the process. There is a property on the activity async after/before; try these and see if the transaction gets committed soon

Comment: Thanks. I would rather not change the transaction behavior just to reach my goal. But it might be a solution in other circumstances. Therefore +1.